# How do I destroy the napalm tank?

Tags: the-division

I'm doing the Napalm Production Site mission, but can't get through even the very first area, because the tank won't explode no matter how much I shoot it.

As far as I know, the tanks are *supposed* to blow up when you shoot the red box on them. Yet they don't. I've tried using different guns, grenades, restarting the mission, restarting the game, all with same result.

Comment: Shooting the red box on the front worked for me (I'm playing on Xbox One). When you are shooting it, does your cursor change to red, or is it white? If I aimed at the tank, my cursor was white and the tank didn't blow up. Aiming at the box on the front made my cursor red, and shooting it caused the tanks to explode.

Comment: I overread that you already know where to shoot but it didn't work out for you. Sadly, I don't know how to fix that problem. Sounds to me like a bug. You could try to play this mission with some other people and see if it works then. If not, you should probably report that bug.

Comment: I had this issue as well. I restarted the game and found that I still could not destroy it. I completely left the mission area, fast traveled to the BoO and back, and was able to complete the mission from the start again.

Comment: What? Bugs in a Ubisoft game? Surely not! What an unprecedented situation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to shoot the red "box" in front of the tank.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug of some sort.
A few of the tanks valves won't take damage, so you apparently need to restart the mission.

I tried fast-traveling to fix it, but it appears you need to reset the mission.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I left the mission and did another mission before returning to this one, i.e. restarted the mission.

Then, I shot the tank out first, and then the cleaners, and it worked. The first time I took out the cleaners first and couldn't take out the tanks afterwards.

Maybe this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I hit options, quit game, rejoined, did a medical encounter then went back and it worked.

Comment: This does answer the question it's a glitch in the game that requires you to restart the mission.